# WCF Service returning Response.Write

Tags: wcf, response.write

I have a WCF service that will be called from a HTML form located in the customer's network.

When the same form is posting the exact same data to an ASP page it expects a response like:

Response.Write "SUCCESS" & vbnewline

How can I send the same response from my WCF service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A WCF service can return any type of data, really. That covers basic primitive types like `int` or `string`, but you can also create more advanced composite types (classes) and send them back.

HOWEVER: WCF is not designed to return HTML markup - that would be the totally wrong approach to things. WCF is a service - a service provides some functionality, you send in some data/parameters, you get back some data/output types.

WCF should not and must not ever be concerned with the actual **representation** of that data on the user's end - that's the job of your user interface - the ASP page or whatever you're dealing with.

So you could have a WCF service like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IMyService
{
  [OperationContract]
  string SomeServiceMethod(string someInput);
}
```

and then call that from your client code something like this:

```
string result = MyService.SomeServiceMethod("Hello!");
```

but you should not ever write a WCF service that returns HTML markup or any other system-specific information.

And since WCF is a message-based system, the WCF service has absolutely no connection to your ASP page - it cannot participate in the ASP lifecycle or access the "Response" object or anything like that.

Comment: Mark,

You absolutely right.
Maybe is not wise to use WCF for something like this.
I don't control the ASP form that posts to my service, which is located at the customer's servers and I can't change it.

The client is looking for the word SUCCESS otherwise it thinks the call to my service failed..

I can use a ASP page to accept the call but I wanted to use WCF for the perfomance.

Comment: @anon2009: you can definitely return a string from your WCF service and make it "SUCCESS" to signal successful completion.

Comment: It didn't work.

Maybe it has to do with the fact that I'm using REST.

   [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "POST",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            UriTemplate = "/Upload")]
        string GetLogFile(Stream LOGFILE);

Comment: Actually doing this it works:

    ebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";

    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusDescription = "SUCCESS";

    return "SUCCESS";